# Is it safe to delete a file that is reportedly bigger than it should be

Tags: linux, filesystems, ntfs, rar

After calling `unrar` on a RAR archive on my 1 TB `NTFS` drive, I am left with a file, that reportedly has a size of `86T`.

Is it safe to delete such file? What is the best way to safely get rid of this file?

Of course, when removed, the file should be unlinked and any actual data belonging to other files should be left unaffected, but I really want to be sure on this one…

###### Edit 1:

`du -h` output in the directory containing the archive + the extracted file:

```
26M .
```

###### Edit 2: Progress and Findings

- `chkdsk F: /scan` did find a corruption in the extracted file.
- `chkdsk F: /f` did `Deleting corrupt attribute record (0x80, "")` (most likely belonging to this file as the record segment number matches) ([attribute 0x80](https://flatcap.github.io/linux-ntfs/ntfs/attributes/data.html))
- The file had 0 size afterwards
- The 0 size file could be deleted
- `chkdsk F: /scan` finds no problems

###### Edit 3: For the Curious

Berore fixing the file with `chkdsk F: /f`:

- the file could not be deleted with Double Commander (file is already in use by no other than Double Commander – probably trying to read the whole file)
- the file could not be deleted with `rm` (on Windows) due to permission denied (I had the `cmd` running as the Administrator)

Comment: For me the attribute 0x80 URL is dead. Alternative: https://flatcap.github.io/linux-ntfs/ntfs/attributes/data.html

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Good you noticed, I couldn't find a better resource before. I updated the link.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

That's not necessarily *erroneously* bigger than your whole drive. Many filesystems including NTFS and ext4 support [sparse files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file), in which areas consisting entirely of 'zero' bytes (`00 00 00 00 ...`) do not have any disk extents allocated to them – such files can easily have an "apparent" size larger than the filesystem, while the real data allocation (aka Windows "size on disk") is smaller.

You can check whether the file is sparse by comparing `du` and `du --apparent`, or by listing files with the `ls -s/--size` option, or using xfs_io to list the individual extents:

```
$ echo Test > large.bin
$ truncate -s 10G large.bin
$ ls -l -s
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root users 10G Jan 10 12:44 large.bin

$ du -h large.bin; du -h --apparent large.bin
4.0K    large.bin
10G     large.bin

$ xfs_io -r -c "fiemap -v" large.bin 
large.bin:
 EXT: FILE-OFFSET      BLOCK-RANGE      TOTAL FLAGS
   0: [0..7]:          4118216..4118223     8   0x1
   1: [8..20971519]:   hole             20971512
```

If in doubt, connect the filesystem to a Windows system (a VM might do) and run `chkdsk X: /scan` or `chkdsk X: /f` and let it verify that no files overlap – or, after deleting the file, use it to verify that the "free space bitmap" doesn't disagree with existing files.

In general, programs would not be able to create *actually* larger files than the filesystem can fit: even file archivers do not have that kind of direct access. If you do end up with an erroneously large file that isn't sparse, this can only be the fault of the OS filesystem driver, in which case **nothing** you do with that filesystem from that point onwards can be guaranteed to be safe (as deletion is done by the same "bad" driver, after all). Use Windows' CHKDSK to verify the filesystem.

For NTFS on Linux, consider switching between the built-in `ntfs3` and the earlier `ntfs-3g` drivers to verify whether they behave the same. Try also extracting your archive on a Linux native filesystem (e.g. on ext4) to see whether it also creates a large file.

Comment: Interesting. But I still feel like the file size is a mistake, because 7zip on Windows produced a file with a reasonable file size (`13M`). I will try checking and let you know.

Comment: It appears that `chkdsk F: /f` did the trick. The file size afterwards was 0 and it could be deleted.

Comment: For completeness: `truncate -s 100T` is a common way to create a sparse file with arbitrary "apparent size" and minimal allocated size (usually a single extent, like 4 KiB).

Comment: @IsawU, I don't know why the 7zip output size would tell you anything meaningful about whether the allocated size is correct or not: a sparse file's empty blocks are going to compress down extremely well since they're all zeros, so _of course_ they don't meaningfully change the size of the resulting zip file. Determining correctness really comes down to consulting the design of whichever application created the file; if it's _meant_ to create something arbitrarily large but sparsely populated, then it's doing what its authors intended.

Comment: @IsawU: you mean 7zip on Windows extracted the same file from the same RAR archive and it was only 13M?  Matching what `unrar v foo.rar` or `7z l foo.rar` showed?  The fact that this happened in the first place is worrying; test your RAM to see if it's failing; that's one possible source of data corruption, in this case of data what was soon going to be written to disk.

Comment: @ThomasWeller [`truncate(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/truncate.1.html) *is* a Linux command.

Comment: @iBug: ah, damn, I meant Windows, of course. Found `fsutil file createnew <name> <size>`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the input, I am sure that the 13 M output from 7zip is (mostly if not completely) correct, because it's an installation `.exe` of an app and the app installed correctly (to my knowledge) from the 13 M file. Of course the installation could be designed to be 86 T, but who would do that? (This was not meant to be a tricky gag gotcha type of thing.)

Comment: @PeterCordes `unrar v myarchive.rar` shows indeed one file with around 13 M of size. Running `sudo memtester 10000 5` (although I have 32 GB of RAM so that was probably not the most "scientific" size to chose). I'm 4 out of 5 tests deep and so far no errors. I might attempt the `unrar` again as there wasn't any long lasting negative effect and I do have good enough backups.

Comment: Based on this – and the fact that the file shrunk after chkdsk – it sounds like the 86 TB is due to a bug in the Linux NTFS driver (are you using ntfs3?). So it _might_ have undesirable results if you try it repeatedly. (Whereas if it had been due to a bug in 'unrar', then the file would have been accepted by chkdsk as a legitimate sparse file.)

Comment: @IsawU: To properly test all your RAM, boot into memtest86+.  (Some distros have a package for it, and/or include it on the live-USB images.)  Also useful is Prime95 stress test to test your CPU / cache and memory controller / memory bus when they're running hot.  But yeah, also try `unrar` again to see if it's repeatable; if this turns out to be a driver bug and this is a test-case for it, that would be useful in getting it fixed.  (I wouldn't count on it being harmless, so good thing you have backups.  Hopefully no lingering damage gets left anywhere chkdsk can't find it...)

Comment: @user1686 From what I understand, if I have `ntfs` in `fstab`, then it will use `ntfs-3g` (which I do have installed).

Comment: Yes, fstype `ntfs` will invoke ntfs-3g while fstype `ntfs3` will use the in-kernel ntfs3 driver. The former has been around for a long time and I wouldn't expect it to have such bugs, while the latter is fairly new.

Comment: OK so the problem is repeatable. Running `unrar e file.rar` again produced now a `87 T` file. Now it might be worth analyzing.

Comment: Is it repeatable on other filesystem types (like on ext4, or on the same NTFS using the ntfs3 driver)?

Comment: I agree, doesn't make sense for an installer. BTW, rar is... hazardous from a security perspective; the license allowing people to make use of the publicly released extraction routines (as adopted by other software like 7zip) doesn't allow changing the code even to fix security bugs, and there are some pretty serious ones.

Comment: @user1686 This was my chain of thought too. It is repeatable on Btrfs. I was able to just delete the file. `btrfs check` did not report any errors (before or after).

Answer (score 10):

In case there is a problem with the disk, I suggest as first step to
ensure that you have backups for the data on the disk.

As the disk is NTFS, it's best handled on Windows as follows.

As second step, run a Command Prompt and enter the following command :

```
chkdsk C:
```

If it finds any errors, the next step will be to fix the problems using
the command :

```
chkdsk /f C:
```

As the last step, if everything completes correctly,
you could delete this file.